# What does it mean 'Infinite dimensional normed spaces'?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I am currently taught about metric-spaces and Hilbert spaces and I got a bit confused, so I try to understand a simple concept to connect the pieces. 
Initially, I thought that a vectors space is a space which is defined by some axioms and the dimension of the vector space is defined by the number of basis (independet vectors). I assume then that a vector space of dimention $R^{n}$ is defined by n basis vectors and each vector in the space is $n$-dimensional. This is my understanding for vector spaces. 
When the normed spaces were introduced I think i missed something. Nomatter the norm used, the output of a norm is a scalar value. How can the normed-space then be infinite? 
Does it mean that it is a vector space of infinite dimensions (as I defined before), the norm of every vector satisifies the axioms of the vector space?
(ie if $x, y$ are in the vector space defined by the basis, then $norm(x)(x+y)$ is still in the same vector space?)
Thank you in advance

Comment: You appear to believe that all vector spaces must be finite dimensional, but this is not so.  Consider the space of all functions $F:  \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.  Show that this is a real vector space.

Comment: I think the simplest example of an infinite dimensional vector space is $\Bbb R [X]=span\{1,X,X^2,\ldots\}$, the real vector space of real polynomials. You can define a norm as $\|\sum a_i X^i\| = \sup_i |a_i|$.

Comment: I believe I understand now. An infinite-dimensional norm space is applying a norm on a infinite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V$ be a vector space. A norm is a **function** $\|.\| : V\to [0,\infty)$. The norm has no bearing on whether $V$ is finite dimensional or infinite dimensional as it is a function from the vector space to the interval $[0,\infty)$.

You can check for yourself. The vector space $P(R)$ of all polynomials with real coefficients is infinite dimensional. But a norm function from $P(R)\to [0, \infty)$ makes perfect sense and has nothing to do with the finite or infinite nature of $P(R)$.

Comment: I see what you mean, so does a normed-space being infinite means that it maps a vector space to a continous interval? If this is the case how do we have a finite normed-space? Or does it mean that it maps a infinite-dimensional vector space to a nother (scalar) space?

Comment: I believe I understand now. An infinite-dimensional norm space is applying a norm on a infinite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 3):

A normed space is a pair $(V,\|\cdot\|)$, where $V$ is a vector space and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm over that vector space. The dimensionality of the space has nothing to do with the norm. For instance, the space $C^0[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional, regardless of the fact that the norm
$$
\|f\|_0 = \max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|
$$

yields only real values (as it is supposed to).

Comment: I see your point here, but what does an infinite dimentional norm-space mean like the Banach spaces. That's how I was introduced to normed spaces, I have some intution but I dont fill satisified with that.

Comment: I believe I understand now. An infinite-dimensional norm space is applying a norm on a infinite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 2):

- A cleaner formulation of "dimension of the vector space is defined by the number of basis (independet vectors)" is:

> The dimension of the vector space is defined as the cardinality of any basis, and the basis are the maximal subsets of independent vectors.

This is *completely independent of any norm* on the vector space, and the field of scalars in this definition is not necessarily $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C.$

- I don't know what you mean by "the norm of every vector satisifies the axioms of the vector space" but I agree with "if x, y are in the vector space defined by the basis, then norm(x)(x+y) is still in the same vector space" because (generally) when a vector space is equipped with a norm, the field of scalars is $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$) and the values of the norm are in $\Bbb R.$
- What holds most my attention is your "each vector in the space is $n$-dimensional". This is probably the central point of your confusion. In $V=\Bbb R^n,$ a vector is $n$-dimensional in the sense that it is defined by $n$ components, which are $n$ functions from $V$ to $\Bbb R.$ *You seem bothered because a norm is **also** a function from $V$ to $\Bbb R,$ and is **only one** function.* But that function does not define the vector, it is just an "additional information". And it is not linear, contrarily to the component functions.

Comment: I was referring to the scalar multiplication distribution. Whether the norm is used like this in order to define a normed-space.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment at all. Is it a new question? Don't you know the axioms of a norm? Can you give some examples of norms on $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I do, but I realised that this part might not be right. I am sorry, I try to undertand how the norms (scalar) can be related to a vector space with vectors of dimension 2 and above.

Comment: Sure, I guess you mean a norm applied in a 2-d vector which can be the sqaure root of the sum of squares of each element

Comment: I believe I understand now. An infinite-dimensional norm space is applying a norm on a infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Yes, exactly! ;)

Comment: Thank you, I think now everything is in place!